# How do I know if a font has a glyph for a given Unicode character?

Tags: delphi, unicode, lazarus

I've seen similar questions answered for C#, PHP, etc. but I was not able to use those solutions in my Pascal work (Lazarus and Delphi).

The question is simple: I'd like to know programmatically if a font has a glyph for a given unicode character - using Lazarus (preferably) or at least Delphi.

In my specific case I'd like to use a unicode arrow char in some TLabel but I'd like to be able to check if that unicode arrow character is present in that font.

As an aside: my current roundabout solution is get TextWidth and TextHeight of the unicode character, and compare it with the TextWidth and TextHeight of a character that I'm sure does NOT have a glyph (say U0001). If they are different, it means the glyph exists. If they are the same, either the character doesn't have a glyph, or the glyph happens to have the same size as the  ("glyph missing) replacement char. Clearly not a very satisfying solution. If you can think of a better roundabout solution, please let me know as well.

Thanks!

Comment: This is platform dependent

Comment: @David: TextWidth on Lazarus seems to work on different platforms, or at least on both Windows and Mac (Darwin) which is what I need in my case.

Comment: The accepted answer is no use on Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`GetGlyphIndices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphindicesw):

> The `GetGlyphIndices` function translates a string into an array of glyph indices. **The function can be used to determine whether a glyph exists in a font.**

And [`GetFontUnicodeRanges()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontunicoderanges)

> **The `GetFontUnicodeRanges` function returns information about which Unicode characters are supported by a font**. The information is returned as a `GLYPHSET` structure.

Comment: That seems exactly what I needed! Thanks.